# Simulator quit unexpectedly while using the libswiftFoundation.dylib plug-in.- error popup

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I have using Xcode - 8.2 and simulator - 7 plus.
I have take screenshot from simulator, when using ⌘ + S and File->Save Screen short. Both cases in the simulator crashes and show popup alert popup of -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This issue was discussed in the Xcode 8.2 release notes.  This is a bug in Foundation on El Capitan.  You will not experience the crash if you upgrade to Sierra.

As a workaround, you can save a screenshot from the command line.  See `xcrun simctl io`

Answer (score 1):

This error message often occurs after an Xcode update has been downloaded via the App store.

To resolve the issue, you simply need to open Xcode so that it can complete component installation.

Once this is done, Simulator should open normally again.